# DataTables split array value and render to multi table in single child row

Tags: javascript, datatables

I using DataTables (https://datatables.net/) for data arrangement, and I already achieved show data in child row, the more I want to do is showing more detail data in it.

I have a JSON data like this

```
{
    "MACHINE": "A01",
    "STATUS": "ENGTEST",
    "TXN_TIME": "2020/09/17 00:04:15",
    "AVAINFO": [
      { 
        "RECIPE": "8EX-001",
        "ava": "Z03341#25#A9161#P#Z03934#5#A9021#P"
      },
      {
        "RECIPE": "8EX-005",
        "ava": "Z80597#3#B3542#L"
      }
    ],
    "ID": "1"
  }
```

and I want to split [ava] with "#" and show the data format in child row like this
[image]

the detail code I have tried as below link
http://live.datatables.net/bohoriga/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

You can build a sub-table inside your `format(d)` function - something like this:

```js
function format (d) {
    var sub_table = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">';
    
    var sub_rows = d.AVAINFO;
    var array_length = sub_rows.length;
    var sub_row = '';

    if (array_length) { // AVAINFO is an array of values:
      for (var i = 0; i < array_length; i++) {
        sub_row = '<tr><td>' + sub_rows[i].RECIPE + '</td><td>' + sub_rows[i].ava + '</td></tr>';
        sub_table = sub_table + sub_row;
      }
    } else { // AVAINFO is a single object - not an array:
      sub_row = '<tr><td>' + d.AVAINFO.RECIPE + '</td><td>' + d.AVAINFO.ava + '</td></tr>';
      sub_table = sub_table + sub_row;
    }

    sub_table = sub_table + '</table>';
    return sub_table;
}
```

However, bear in mind that the code sample you link to in the question has some other bugs in it, which need to be fixed before my proposed approach will work.

For example, the DataTable refers to non-existent columns (e.g. `"targets": [4,5,6,7,8]` and elsewhere) and to non-existent data, e.g. `Type`.

Also, the JSON data in `$ajax_data` is not valid. It needs to be an array:

```js
$ajax_data = [
  {
    "MACHINE": "A01",
    "STATUS": "ENGTEST",
    "TXN_TIME": "2020/09/17 00:04:15",
    "AVAINFO": [
      { 
        "RECIPE": "8EX-001",
        "ava": "Z03341#25#A9161#P#Z03934#5#A9021#P"
      },
      {
        "RECIPE": "8EX-005",
        "ava": "Z80597#3#B3542#L"
      }
    ],
    "ID": "1"
  },
  {
    "MACHINE": "A03",
    "STATUS": "IDLE",
    "TXN_TIME": "2020/11/30 21:25:43",
    "AVAINFO": {
      "RECIPE": "8PI",
      "ava": "Z90018#25#B1825#P#Z80238#20#B1115#P#Z20018#13#B0095#L#"
    },
    "ID": "2"
  }
];
```

Comment: Thank you @andrewjames, I renew the link of the example and tried to use `slice()` and `.split()` to solve it, could u give me more advice to approach the result?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. What specific problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

I reference other related disscusions then solved this by add `.splice()`, `.slice()`, and use loop to create sub-row.

```
function separate(arr, size) {
  let res = [];
  while (arr.length) {
    res.push(arr.splice(0, size));
  }
  return res;
}

function format ( d ) {
  var tr = '';
  d.AVAINFO.forEach(function (item) {
    var  a = item.ava.split("#");
    result = separate(a, 4)   
    //console.log(result);
  tr += '<tr>'+          
            '<th>Recipe</th>'+
            '<th>ORDER</th>'+
            '<th>QTY</th>'+
            '<th>CODE</th>'+
            '<th>TYPE</th>'+
        '</tr>';
  
    for (i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
        tr += '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>'+item.RECIPE+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+result[i][0]+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+result[i][1]+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+result[i][2]+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+result[i][3]+'</td>'+
        '</tr>';
    }
  });
  
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
      tr +
      '</table>';
}
```

Comment: Nice! - glad you figured out what you needed.